# Aggregation relationship between client and Person/Organization

Tags: uml, domain-model

I have a **Client** object which will either have a **Person** object or **Organization** object in it. These **Person** objects or **Organization** objects might have relations to other objects independent of the **Client** object. In this case should I use a General Aggregation association between `Client -> Person` and `Client -> Organization` where the **Client** object is the whole.

Also note these scenarios:

1. **Person** might be a normal **Person** in some scenarios like; **Person** makes payment on behalf of **Client**(**Organization**)
2. **Person** might be a **Client** which bought a **Product** from Us.
3. **Person** might be a **Supplier**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you really didn't provide enough information, it sounds like you're describing a typical [Role Class Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role_Class_Model).

I suspect that your Client doesn't really **have** a Person or an Organization, but rather that Person or an Organization **is** a Client, or IOW, either a Person or an Organization can play a role of a Client in a certain relationship.

There are various ways to model this, and no single correct solution. You might find this [article](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2002_09/column2/) helpful

Comment: The Client object will have more (client)information apart from the data that the Person or Organization class would have.

Comment: I have checked the article you provided and I prefer no. 4 (Role Class Generalization) but as PHP does not support Multiple Inheritance I will try no. 3 (Role Class Association) which is what I suggested but it is using a normal association.

Answer (score 1):

don´t forget an xor constraint between both associations (since a client cannot be connected to both a person and a organization)

Comment: Do you know how to do it in BOUML.

Comment: And are you agreeing that I should use a General Aggregation?

Comment: There is not enough information to see if this should be an aggregation or a normal association but the semantics is almost the same so it´s not that important